# Can I jump low walls more effectively?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When I want to jump over a low (cover) wall directly, Shepard first takes cover, and then jumps if I continue to press the space bar and moving forward.

Is there a way to do it directly?
I want her to approach it running and jump it without first taking cover (she looks silly and paranoid when there are no enemies in sight).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, if you sprint at a shoulder-high wall and press your "action" key twice, Shepard will slide over the top or climb without first taking cover.

The timing can be a might tricky to get the hang of, but this *is* possible in Mass Effect 3, unlike the previous game.

Comment: I am *so* glad they implemented this!

Comment: The logic is you must first touch the obstacle before you tap again; if you tap before you touch the obstacle it won't happen. If you wait too long to tap after touching the obstacle you will hunker down. That is the timing window you have. This logic is 100%. (You do have to be approaching the obstacle while holding the button.)